# Order by facebook likes (PHP)

Tags: php, javascript, facebook

I've got a site with lots of news, however i'm wondering if there is any way i can sort my articles by facebook likes? and how can i do this without killing my server by updating all articles x times in a day?

first i was thinking doing something like this,

```
$source_url = "http://example.com/";  //This could be anything URL source including stripslashes($_POST['url'])

$url = "http://api.facebook.com/restserver.php?method=links.getStats&urls=".urlencode($source_url);
$xml = file_get_contents($url);
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml);
$likes =  $xml->link_stat->like_count;
```

But this would kill my server if i did an update on all my articles so..

Any suggestions or snippets i can look at? maybe i can use some javascript or something? dunno.

Comment: What kill your server? The file_get_contents?

Comment: If i do one request, it's ok, but imagine doing this with 1000+ articles. Looks like i'm going for a ajax request when they click on the button.

Answer (score 1):

Create a db table to hold the facebook likes (URL, Likes, Timestamp). Upon page load, if Timestamp > now + a certain amount of time, refresh the Likes in the table. The data could be slightly out of date, but if you had a refresh time of 5-10 minutes, I would think it would be pretty close most of the time.

Answer (score 0):

Well first of all you should drop the old REST interface and switch to the [Graph API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/).

When you do that you'll be able to get data for more than one object in a single request, by specifying a comma separated list of the URLs you want. You can do this both from PHP with a simple GET, or via Javascript with a call to FB.api().

Snippet from the doc:

> You can also request multiple objects in a single query using the "ids" query parameter. For example, the URL https://graph.facebook.com?ids=arjun,vernal returns both profiles in the same response.
>
> The "ids" query parameter also accepts URLs. This is useful for finding IDs of URLs in the Open Graph. For example: https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0117500/

In any case, if you need frequent access to your table, the best (or, more likely, only) solution is locally caching Facebook's data.